# bootstrap.js: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

When I use the Google Chrome Developer Tool in my web page developed using ASP.NET Core 1.0 (.NET Framework) project I detect the error: `bootstrap.js: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3`. Can't figure out the cause of the error. The `source view` of my web page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
Hello world.... and other content
.....

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/site.js?v=EWaMeWsJBYWmL2g_KkgXZQ5nPe-a3Ichp0LEgzXczKo"></script>   

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"requestId":"a5c076a64ad7453f951bb2251bd6eec3","requestMappingFromServer":false}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:58884/74edce98fdb542fc9b4a680a345ade26/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you might be including two different versions of jQuery. What version is the jQuery in this file: <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>?

Comment: @LanceTurri The version in that file is: `jQuery JavaScript Library v3.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Except these lines

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Put this line :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" ></script>
```

And btw your question is duplicate I think :)